# Set variable to result of "Find" in batch-file

Tags: batch-file, find

I would like to set a variable based on the number of lines in a file that contain a give string.

Something like:

```
set isComplete = 0
%isComplete% = find /c /i "Transfer Complete" "C:\ftp.LOG"
IF %isComplete% > 0 ECHO "Success" ELSE ECHO "Failure"
```

Or:

```
set isComplete = 0
find /c /i "Transfer Complete" "C:\ftp.LOG" | %isComplete%
IF %isComplete% > 0 ECHO "Success" ELSE ECHO "Failure"
```

Neither of those options work, obviously.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

from the command line

```
for /f "tokens=3" %f in ('find /c /i "Transfer Complete" "C:\ftp.LOG"') do set isComplete=%f
```

from the batch script

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%f in ('find /c /i "Transfer Complete" "C:\ftp.LOG"') do set isComplete=%%f
```

Comment: This is great.  However, I should have mentioned I need this to work with a path that has a space.  The quotes don't seem to help.  Ugh.  So...

for /f "tokens=3" %%f in ('find /c /i "Transfer Complete" "C:\test path\ftp.LOG"') do set isComplete=%%f

sets isComplete to "PATH\FTP.LOG:", where the error, I guess, is caused by the space.

Comment: You need to use the "usebackq" option of the for command so that you can put quotes around the path: for /f "usebackq tokens=3" %%f in (`find /c /i "Transfer Complete" "C:\test path\ftp.log"`) do set isComplete %%f

Answer (score 14):

You don't need to use the `for` command; `find` will set the `ERRORLEVEL` to one of these values, based on the result:

- 0, At least one match was found.
- 1, no matches were found.
- 2 or more, an error occurred.

Since it looks like you just want to see if the transfer completed, and not the total count of times the string appears, you can do something like this:

```
@echo OFF

@find /c /i "Transfer Complete" "C:\test path\ftp.LOG" > NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    @echo Success
) else (
    @echo Failure
)
```

Comment: Actually I'm now expecting a count of 2 (two files transferred) . . . so two occurrences of "Transfer Complete" = Success.

Comment: The `IF %isComplete% > 0` is a little confusing then; is what you really want `IF %isComplete% EQU 2`?